# Find Adwords ads from a specific website?

Tags: google-ads-api

Is it possible with the Google Adwords API to get ads (both text and images) from any website, even if I don't own it?

For example, I'd like to see all ads that www.website.com does. Is there a way to extract that data?

There are sites online that do it, so there must be a way, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdWords API only displays the Ads that you have created.
 For any given AdWords account, there has to be a Campaign, which have AdGroups, which have the Ads and the user can only access Ads within that particular account.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how websites that sell ads like whatrunswhere.com and moat.com find their ads?